# I cant install Skype on Kali Linux x64

Tags: linux, skype

```
root@kali:~/Desktop# dpkg -i skype-debian_4.3.0.37-1_i386.deb
(Reading database ... 316914 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to replace skype 4.3.0.37-1 (using skype-debian_4.3.0.37-1_i386.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement skype ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of skype:
 skype depends on libc6 (>= 2.3.6-6~).
 skype depends on libc6 (>= 2.7).
 skype depends on libgcc1 (>= 1:4.1.1).
 skype depends on libqt4-dbus (>= 4:4.5.3).
 skype depends on libqt4-network (>= 4:4.8.0).
 skype depends on libqt4-xml (>= 4:4.5.3).
 skype depends on libqtcore4 (>= 4:4.7.0~beta1).
 skype depends on libqtgui4 (>= 4:4.8.0).
 skype depends on libqtwebkit4 (>= 2.1.0~2011week13).
 skype depends on libstdc++6 (>= 4.2.1).
 skype depends on libx11-6.
 skype depends on libxext6.
 skype depends on libxss1.
 skype depends on libxv1.
 skype depends on libssl1.0.0.
 skype depends on libpulse0.
 skype depends on libasound2-plugins.

dpkg: error processing skype (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus ...
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 skype
root@kali:~/Desktop#
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems like a simple dependency issue. Not 100% sure about Kali Linux, but did find [these Kali Linux specific Skype installation instructions](https://2c2bn.wordpress.com/2013/10/08/how-to-install-skype-on-kali-linux/) that seem solid. Specifically they suggest the following:

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

The `-f` flag stands for `--fix-broken` and according to the `man` page it will:

> Fix; attempt to correct a system with broken dependencies in place.

So after running that run this line again:

```
dpkg -i skype-debian_4.3.0.37-1_i386.deb
```

And if that still chokes, then be sure to enable multi-arch like this:

```
dpkg --add-architecture i386
apt-get update
```

And then run those commands again.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a shared library issue. Run the following as root:

```
apt-get -f install && apt-get update && dpkg -i skype-debian_4.3.0.37-1_i386.deb && --install
```

Answer (score 0):

You could give the Skype dynamic package a try.  If that doesn't work, you can track down an old version of Skype static, it'll work on just about any system.  There's a fairly recent version at : http://slackware.uk/slacky/slackware64-14.1/network/skype_static/4.2.0.13/